# Запись и чтение структуры с помощью бинарного файла

Tags: c, файлы

Есть такой код:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

#define ERROR_FILE_OPEN -1

int i = 0;

struct scan_info{
    char model[25]; // наименование модели
    int price; // цена
    double x_size; // горизонтальный размер области сканирования
    double y_size; // вертикальный размер области сканирования
    int optr; // оптическое разрешение
    int grey; // число градаций серого
};

void output_bin(long N, struct scan_info *task_struct)
{
    FILE *f_output = NULL;

    f_output = fopen("task.bin", "rb");
    if (f_output == NULL){
        printf("Error opening file");
        getch();
        exit(ERROR_FILE_OPEN);
    }

    fseek(f_output, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fread(&N, sizeof(long), 1, f_output);
    fseek(f_output, 4, SEEK_SET);
    printf("\nЧитаем структуру из бианрного файла\n");
    printf("Число записей: ");
    printf("%i",N);
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
        fread(&task_struct[i], sizeof(struct scan_info), 1, f_output);
        printf("%s\n",task_struct[i]);
    }   

    fclose(f_output);
}

void input_bin(long N, struct scan_info *task_struct)
{

    FILE *f_input = NULL;

    f_input = fopen("task.bin", "w+b");
    if (f_input == NULL){
        printf("Error opening file");
        getch();
        exit(ERROR_FILE_OPEN);
    }

    fseek(f_input, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fwrite(&N, sizeof(long), 1, f_input);
    fseek(f_input, 4, SEEK_SET);
    for (i=0; i<N; i++){
        if (task_struct[i].price  >= 200){
            fwrite(&task_struct[i], sizeof(struct scan_info), 1, f_input);
        }
    }   

    fclose(f_input);    
}

void printf_struct(long N, struct scan_info *task_struct)
{
    printf("\nПолученная структура\n");
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
        printf("\nНазвание: ");
        printf("%s\n",task_struct[i].model);
        printf("Цена: ");
        printf("%i\n",task_struct[i].price);
        printf("Горизонтальный размер области сканирования: ");
        printf("%d\n",task_struct[i].x_size);
        printf("Вертикальный размер области сканирования: ");
        printf("%d\n",task_struct[i].y_size);
        printf("Оптическое разрешение: ");
        printf("%i\n",task_struct[i].optr);
        printf("Число градаций серого: ");
        printf("%i\n",task_struct[i].grey);
    }               
}

void scanf_struct(long N, struct scan_info *task_struct)
{       
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
        printf("\nНазвание: ");
        scanf("%s",&task_struct[i].model);
        printf("Цена: ");
        scanf("%i",&task_struct[i].price);
        printf("Горизонтальный размер области сканирования: ");
        scanf("%d",&task_struct[i].x_size);
        printf("Вертикальный размер области сканирования: ");
        scanf("%d",&task_struct[i].y_size);
        printf("Оптическое разрешение: ");
        scanf("%i",&task_struct[i].optr);
        printf("Число градаций серого: ");
        scanf("%i",&task_struct[i].grey);
    }
}

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    long N;
    struct scan_info *task_struct;

    printf("Введите количество записей о сканерах: ");
    scanf("%i", &N);
    task_struct = (struct scan_info*)malloc(N*sizeof(struct scan_info));

    scanf_struct(N, task_struct);
    printf_struct(N, task_struct);
    input_bin(N, task_struct);
    output_bin(N, task_struct);

    return 0;
}
```

Необходимо записать структуру в файл, а потом считать её из файла. Подскажите что я делаю неправильно. Записывает только первое поле структуры.

Comment: `if (task_struct[i].price  >= 200){` - может, у вас только одна запись под это условие попадает? Еще - `fseek(f_input, 4, SEEK_SET);` - вот это явно лишнее (оно не мешает... но...) и, кстати, почему у вас функция вывода (output) называется input (и наоборот)?... И еще - вы записываете явно меньше данных, чем пытаетесь считывать - потому что в цикле из N итераций не все итерации пишут. Но все читают...

Comment: В ``printf_struct`` все печатается?

Comment: @Эникейщик Да, но не из бинарного файла

Comment: @Harry Немного не понял про названия функций, вроде бы всё корректно, да и не важно. Записывается только поле model, а не целая структура. В этом и проблема

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Честно? хочется материться :(

Что выведет ваша инструкция

```
printf("%s\n",task_struct[i]);
```

Ну? Чего вы ждете от нее? Что она вам и модель выведет, и цену, и разрешение?

Что попросили - то и вывела: символы по указанному адресу до нулевого. Т.е по сути первое поле - модель. Считано все, но вывести на экран вы по сути попросили только модель (и то случайно - потому что она - первое поле... была бы там цена - вы бы вообще спрашивали, почему программа вылетает аварийно...)

Все нормально работает.

А насчет того, что я об именах функций написал.

`input` обычно переводится как *ввод*. stdin знаете? Из него читают.
Точно так же и `output` - вывод. В файл, на экран...

А у вас `input` для вывода в файл, `output` для ввода из файла. Все равно как `read` для записи сделать, `write` для чтения - сбивает с толку. Вас же самого сбивать будет...

Ну и - то, что число записываемых и читаемых записей будет разным - это исправление на вашей совести...

Comment: Настолько токсично звучало в голове, что засмеялся :D